# SPF passed, DKIM signed and DMARC added but email goes to spam

Tags: email, centos7, postfix-mta

I have configured DKIM, SPF and DMARC correct and from the email headers it seems to be working fine but the emails I sent from my SMTP server are marked as spam. Here is my email headers

```
Received: from SG2APC01HT253.eop-APC01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (10.163.105.24) by SG2PR03MB1582.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS via
 SG2PR06CA0014.APCPRD06.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Tue, 7 Feb 2017 02:03:11 +0000
Received: from SG2APC01FT015.eop-APC01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (10.152.250.60) by SG2APC01HT253.eop-APC01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (10.152.251.100) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id 15.1.874.2; Tue, 7 Feb
 2017 02:03:09 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 191.101.230.42)
 smtp.mailfrom=ezpc.com.my; hotmail.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)
 header.d=ezpc.com.my;hotmail.com; dmarc=bestguesspass action=none
 header.from=ezpc.com.my;
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of ezpc.com.my designates
 191.101.230.42 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;
 client-ip=191.101.230.42; helo= mail.ezpc.com.my;
Received: from BAY004-MC1F48.hotmail.com (10.152.250.55) by
 SG2APC01FT015.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.250.181) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id 15.1.874.2 via Frontend
 Transport; Tue, 7 Feb 2017 02:03:06 +0000
X-IncomingTopHeaderMarker: OriginalChecksum:B3C91582F4E1A8BEB3081753A75091AB6E10F9554C8EB64EF3F4DBAEBFBBCCAD;UpperCasedChecksum:FDA1A8FF432113AA359CED44F62CC1B29335E24D01725A791958063140028963;SizeAsReceived:1267;Count:16
Received: from mail.ezpc.com.my ([191.101.230.42]) by BAY004-MC1F48.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
     Mon, 6 Feb 2017 18:03:04 -0800
Received: by mail.ezpc.com.my (Postfix, from userid 48)
    id AB46E2213CB; Mon,  6 Feb 2017 21:03:03 -0500 (EST)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 mail.ezpc.com.my AB46E2213CB
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=ezpc.com.my;
    s=default; t=1486432983;
    bh=9v0acwudeB20jRA3DCLi3/n8gPxEJUSqP+DRE97Rs/8=;
    h=To:Subject:From:Date:From;
    b=Pr71KmBKnlBDX6KEY3PNzaRVqj1njANZe4fVyDI/3a+uNDCqE933329nhyoaeyS2U
     c5pbo1szpI2lI5Io9AV5q33w/HeIYnsGvstpM9e/mtpBUeNoYk7ajIeJldSyI1kbGv
     AtYp7oGy2ltmDcO4nkwqEBRpkPJr3jwcKhY6Ucys=
```

Any idea on fixing the problem?

Comment: what's your sending domain!?

Answer (score 0):

Your ip reputation is neutral (which is good but can be improved)
http://www.senderbase.org/lookup/?search_string=191.101.230.42

As long as all those settings are configured correct, then you should use this form from Microsoft!
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&locale=en-us&ccsid=636225696037961710